# NodeJS callback and return statement

Tags: node.js, function, asynchronous, callback, return

I'm writing a Server-side application based on NodeJS.
The application listen on some TCP and UDP ports for incoming messages, when the messages arrive they are parsed and the relevant data are stored into a MySQL database. The whole thing works fine and NodeJS capability to handle parallel concurrent requests is amazing.
However reading around the feedback about NodeJS dangers I've found something that brings confusion to me: the question is about callbacks.
Imagine the code below:

```
function ParseMessage(payload,callback_ko,callback_ok) {
  // here we evaluate the parsed_message content, err is set if parsing errors occurs
  ....
  if(!err) {
    // if there are no errors invoke the callback_ok to let the flow continue passing the parsed content
    if(typeof callback_ok == 'function') {
      callback_ok(parsed_message);
      }
  else {
    // if error occurs invoke the callback_ko passing the payload to let the flow continue in another path, maybe attempt another parsing
    if(typeof callback_ko =='function') {
      callback_ko(payload);
      }
    }
  return;   // <---- Ensure the functions ends
  }
```

The code `if(typeof callback == 'function')` is placed to avoid to call arguments passed to *ParseMessage* function that is **not a function** (in that case the *ParseMessage* simply must exit returning anything as result).
My doubt is about the `return;` statement:
I know the **return** statement **MUST** always be present (correct me if I'm wrong with that) in order to allow the async function ends properly. As we're not returning anything here (we're invoking callbacks here) we simply don't return anything on it, but I don't know if the place where return statement is written is the right one. In other words, should I place the return statement at the end of the function or should I have something like this, instead:

```
function ParseMessage(payload,callback_ko,callback_ok) {
  // here we evaluate the parsed_message content, err is set if parsing errors occurs
  ....
  if(!err) {
    // if there are no errors invoke the callback_ok to let the flow continue passing the parsed content
    if(typeof callback_ok == 'function') {
      callback_ok(parsed_message);
      }
    return;   // <---- Ensure the functions ends
  else {
    // if error occurs invoke the callback_ko passing the payload to let the flow continue in another path, maybe attempt another parsing
    if(typeof callback_ko =='function') {
      callback_ko(payload);
      }
    return;   // <---- Ensure the functions ends
    }
  }
```

I've found that someone also suggest to write something like `return callback(payload);`. What's the most correct strategy?

Comment: It really depends on your logic. But looking at your example i think it doesn't make sense to use `return` in these functions, since you return nothing from function

Comment: @TheReason: that's what I guessed as well, until I read this [link](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/994), where it's stated that invoking a callback without returning from function is **formally an error**. I've found several similar statement all around. What's the truth?

Comment: You do not need any return statement for the async function to end correctly. In your case, if you don't need any immediate result returned from your function, you don't need any return statement.  The link you mention is the case if they encounter an error, they want to call to error callback and immediately exit the function without running any logic outside the if block.

Comment: @HenryLiu, so what happens when return is missing and the argument passed is not a function? Will the function end properly even without return? I don't want to discover thousands functions floating around in server memory waiting a closure that will never arrive, is it possible a situation like that?

Comment: see [here] (https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/994) for confirmation.